# Laravel formula para calcular datos antes de guardarlo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-4

Tengo este endpoint que recibe los parámetros de la request weight i height i los guarda en BD como un registro , pero tengo el campo "IMC" que es un campo calculado a partir de estos dos valores y para ello uso un método de un servicio que hace los cálculos y me devuelve un valor.

Mi pregunta es , cuando hago el Profiles::create($data) como le paso allí imc para que me lo guarde en BD?

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

    $input = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'weight' => 'decimal',
        'height' => 'decimal'
    ]);

    UtilsService::calculateImc($request->input('weight'),$request->input('height'));

    if($validator->fails()){
        return $this->jsonValidatorFailedResponse($validator->errors());
    }

    $profile= Profiles::create($input);

    return $profile;

    }
```

Comment: IMC pertenece al mismo modelo Profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, la mas sencilla seria hacer un merge con el request->all():

```
$imc = UtilsService::calculateImc($request->input('weight'),$request->input('height'));

Profiles::create(array_merge($input, [‘imc’ => $imc]));
```

o por otro lado en vez de usar el create del modelo hacerlo por pasos:

```
$p = new Profiles();
$p->weight = $request->input('weight');
$p->height = $request->input('height');
$p->imc = UtilsService::calculateImc($p->weight,$p->height);
$p->save();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias así lo he resuelto.